# can someone explain to me the use of unicode_escape as an encoding argument in python 3.6?

Tags: python, dataframe, decode, encode, unicode-escapes

I work with large pandas dataframes on a daily basis, which gets fed information that we parse from a webAPI (xml encoding is utf-8) local to our network.

After I feed the dataframe and export as a csv file I start getting encoding errors (local machine is cp1252) which I've had to deal with the past few weeks.

The solution I finally found was [here][1] under tangfucious's response.

```
    df['crumbs'] = df['crumbs'].map(lambda x: x.encode('unicode-escape').decode('utf-8'))
```

a line of code that takes a string and encodes it using `.encode=('unicode_escape')`, decoding into utf-8 after.

Can someone explain to me how this code works? Unfortunately, I'm a noob and new to SO so I wasn't able to comment on his response

What is the purpose of unicode-escape under the hood (aside from the obvious, adding a \ to each unicode code point).? 
How does this affect decoding into utf-8? Why is this necessary? Isn't it always better to encode/decode using the same encoding?

Is there another use in using 'unicode_escape'?

Comment: I suspect you're heading down the wrong direction here. Ideally, your dataframe would work in Unicode, and you'd set the encoding of your csv using the `encoding` attribute on the `to_csv` call. `'unicode_escape'` is for producing an ascii encoding of the Unicode string that can be read as a string literal by Python.

Comment: As for "Isn't it always better to encode/decode using the same encoding" - well, that depends on what will be reading the encoded output. If you're working with a cp1252 environment downstream, it may be best to write something that it will understand by default by encoding to cp1252. I'd prefer to try to work out how to make the downstream environment behave better (just for instance, I believe Excel may ask you the encoding if you load your .csv using the "import" option rather than "open") but sometimes that's not possible.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer! So unicode_escape re-produces the string in an ascii encoding, which can then be decoded as utf-8?  actually made that exact change in the to_csv encoding argument (encoding = 'utf-8') when I exported the dataframes as a tab delimited text file. However for some reason that fix alone didn't resolve any of the character errors, so I had to add the unicode_escape encode first. I know python 3 str repr defaults to utf-8, but I'm still unsure as to why that was necessary.

Comment: could you possibly elaborate on how to make downstream environment behave better? and why this is important? links to other threads will also be appreciated if this was asked already. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, it depends heavily on how you're using that .csv - the best thing would be to have whatever you're using to look at the .csv accept utf-8 input. Decode utf-8 input from your XML, resulting in a Unicode pandas dataframe. Work with it as needed, but don't encode the Unicode into bytes. Only do that when writing it to a .csv, using an encoding that can both represent everything in the dataframe (utf-8 can do that, cp1252 might or might not depending on the input). And figure out how to get your tools that work further with the .csv to be aware of the encoding.

Comment: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/ is a good starting point if you're not super familiar with Unicode and various encodings, if a bit dated in its web-specific discussions.